# Make mockito less strict with object comparison

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following code:

```
public JSONObject addProductToOrder(int orderId, int productId, String name, double price) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("orderId", orderId);
        json.put("productId", productId);
        json.put("name", name);
        json.put("price", price);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Debugger.out(e);
    }
    return this.dataSource.write("/orderItems/addproductToOrder", json);
}
```

I want to test so using Mockito and I have done the following:

```
public void getOrder() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{result: 'OK', error: 0}");
    doReturn(json)
            .when(this.clientSpy) // this.clientSpy = Mockito.spy(client);
            .post("/orderItems/addProductToOrder", new JSONObject("{productId: 1, orderId: 1, price: 15.99, name: 'Product 1'}"));

    OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(this.api);
    assertEquals("OK", orderItem.addProductToOrder(1, 1, "Product 1", 15.99).get("result"));
}
```

The way I understand things, my `doReturn()` is not triggered because `new JSONObject() !== new JSONObject()`.

Is there a way to make it not compare the objects, but instead just the contents?

Comment: If I understand it right, you should implement the equals method with the contents you want to be compared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that Mockito is calling *equals()* to compare the object that you provided to the specification to the one that is used for the actual method call.

Basically, there are three options:

- if you just provide an object, equals() is used to compare
- then you have a variety of other [ArgumentMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html), such as `any()` or `isNull()`. Please note: when using such matchers, **all** arguments must be matched, you can't do: `foo(any(), 5)`  for example.
- if that doesn't do: you can also use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253040/example-on-mockitos-argumentcaptor). Meaning: instead of having Mockito compare objects, you simply *record* the object that was passed to the mock. And then you add another step in your test case where you check the captured argument as required.

Answer (score 0):

This argThat function can help you.

```
    private static String eqJson(String expectedJson) {
    return argThat(argument -> {
        try {
            JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, argument, true);
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your test

```
    // import
    import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
    import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat;

    // then
    then(mock).should(times(1)).method(eqJson(expectedJson));
```