# Mockito: How to set thenReturn() dynamically?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a method which accepts a list of items. I'd like the mocked method to return a corresponding list of the same size (i.e. `List<Results>`)

More generally, is it possible to set the returned value dynamically, with respect to the given input?

The problem is that I have multiple tests for the same method. Test A is for an empty list and test B is for a list with multiple objects. Yet, I have only one `@Before` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`thenAnswer`](https://www.javarticles.com/2015/07/mockito-stubbing-with-custom-answers.html), probably in combination with an [ArgumentCaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253040/example-on-mockitos-argumentcaptor) to achieve that.

But the real answer is: consider not doing that.

Unit tests should be straight forward. When something fails, you *quickly* look at the unit test and you already know where to look in the production code to spot the root cause. Anything that adds complexity to your tests *might* make that harder.

In other words: instead of thinking up complex *test* code that gives dynamic results ... rather write multiple simple tests. You are in control of what goes int your test. So when you want tests that receive 2, 3, 5 arguments, and you need to return 2, 3, 5 elements for each case: then write 3 different tests.

Comment: I see, maybe I overcomplicated it. I understand I shall define an ad-hoc when-thenReturn for every test. Thanks!

Comment: @yaseco You are very welcome, I am glad that this "non answer" came over helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the right way to do this would be:

```
import org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers;
String[] logEntry = // Some initialization code
List<String> logEntryList = Arrays.asList(logEntry); 
when(tuple.getString(1)).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(logEntryList));
```

On each invocation, successive elements of logEntry array are returned. Thus, *i*th invocation of `tuple.getString(1)` returns *i*th element of logEntry array.

<del>P.S: The example in documentation of `returnsElementsOf` (as of this writing) is not updated (it still uses `ReturnsElementsOf` example): http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsElementsOf(java.util.Collection)it</del>

EDIT: Javadoc is now updated:
https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsElementsOf-java.util.Collection-