# Is there a way in Mockito to return the object if it was received?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Is there a way to return the received object in Mockito? I want to do this simulating the saving of the object in the database.
Something like this:

```
someClass someObj = ...;

when(dataProviderMock.insert(someObj))
    .then(
          when(dataProviderMock.read(someObj.getId()))
         .thenReturn(someObj)
    );
```

Comment: there is no need to nest the statements, if the insert method returns an Object you could write it like this when(dataProviderMock.insert(eq(someObj)).thenReturn(someObj);  given that the equals method of your "someObj" checks the Id. Am I getting your question right?

Comment: not really. what you wrote is basically a return for the insert method. What I want is that the "read" returns the object when it was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is an `ArgumentCaptor` from Mockito check out this other question

[Example on Mockito's argumentCaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253040/example-on-mockitos-argumentcaptor)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the benefit of it, but this will work:

// Keep the saved objects in a map

```
 Map<Integer, Object> savedObjects = new HashMap<>(); 



// Saves the object in the map
when(dataProviderMock.insert(any(SomeClass.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                SomeClass someObj = ((SomeClass)invocation.getArgument(0));
                savedObjects.put(someObj.getId(), someObj);
                return null;
            }
        });

// retrieves the object from the map or null if it was not previously saved
when(dataProviderMock.read(any(Integer.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Integer id = ((Integer)invocation.getArgument(0));
                return savedObjects.get(id);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tha lloks like what I wanted. I will test it out. Thanks. The usage is - test a controller. And I want to mock saving and retrieving users from and to the DB

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correct, you want to return an object when you call the insert. 
Provided your insert function has return type of someObj. you can directly return the object using

```
    when(dataProviderMock.insert(someObj)).thenReturn(someObj)
```

If your return type is `void` for `dataProviderMock.insert()` function, you may do this:

```
    doNothing().doReturn(someObj).when(dataProviderMock).insert(someObj);
```

Comment: Hi, it is ideed not what I want. I want that the dataProviderMock read returns the object when it was inserted. basically read(...)==null before insertion; after read(...)==obj